# Displaying text backwards

Tags: c++, file, dynamic, txt

I am trying to display text file backwards line by line. I want to do this with char and dynamic allocation. I allocate a 2d dynamic array for this purpose. But the problem is that every line I read in the erase the precedent.
This is my code :

```
int main()
{
    char path[256]; string name;
    cout << "Enter path:" << endl; cin >> path;

    ifstream file(path);
    if (!file) { cout << "ERROR" << endl; return -1; }

    char** sentence = new char* [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        *sentence = new char[120];

    char line[120];
    int index = 0;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file.getline(line, 120);  
        sentence[index++] = line; //Erase precedent line
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        cout << sentence[i] << endl;

    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why should it be 2d?

Comment: Why do you say it's a duplicate, this is not the same question

Comment: @rcoding I'll reopen, but you should fix [that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) first in any case. Also you should rather use `std::string` as type for line, and `std::vector<std::string>` for `sentence`. This `sentence[index++] = line;` leaks memory like a sieve.

Comment: I know this is a problem, but because I have to use char and not std::string, I think there isn't a different way. Like I say I have to use regular array and char*

Comment: "_I have to use char and not std::string_" - Wait, what?! Why wasn't that information in the question? Is there something else you aren't allowed to use?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `std::cin` and `std::cout` are synchronized. That means that when you write a prompt to `std::cout` and then try to read input, `std::cin`, will get flushed. There's no need for that `std::endl` in the prompt for the file path.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether there is a more efficient way to solve this.

```
void readFile(char *fileName){
        char c;
        std::ifstream myFile(fileName,std::ios::ate);
        std::streampos size = myFile.tellg();
        for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
            myFile.seekg(-i,std::ios::end);
            myFile.get(c);
            printf("%c\n",c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When open the file, I use ios::ate to set the file position to the end of the file and use seekg method to read back.

Comment: If i understand your code, this will reverse every char. I want to reverse all line not every char

Answer (score 0):

This is not doing what you think:

```
   sentence[index++] = line; //Erase precedent line
```

This assigns the address of `line` into `sentence[index]`. Which is not what you want because at the end of the loop all values in `sentence` point at `line` (thus leaking all the dynamically allocated memory).

To make this work you need to copy the string into the destination.

```
  std::copy(line, strlen(line), sentence[index++]);
```

---

However: This is probably not the best solution. You should be using C++ objects rather than low level C-Strings. The C++ objects would have solved this for you without any need for manual copying or dynamic allocation.

A quick hint is that new/delete or probably a bad idea for beginers. If your code contains them you are doing something wrong (or writting C and happen to use the C++ compiler to compile the code).

```
int main()
{
    /* 
       Replace this with std::vector<std::string>
    char** sentence = new char* [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        *sentence = new char[120];
    */
    // Great thing about vectors is that they will resize.
    std::vector<std::string>  sentence;
   
    std::string line;
    // Use the read operation as the condition of the loop
    // If you fail to read then you should not add it to sentence.
    // Note `line` will dynamically re-size for any size of line.
    while(std::getline(file, line))
    {
        sentence.push_back(line);
    }

    // You can finish it.
    // Iterate over the `sentence` backwards and print them out.
}
```